# Unable to locate package whatsie in kali linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux

I am getting this when I try to install whatsie on my kali Version 2020.3.

I used this  -
`apt-get install whatsie`

I am getting error as

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package whatsie
```

I refer to this - https://ostechnix.com/whatsie-simple-desktop-client-whatsapp-web/ and followed the steps for **Install Whatsie on Ubuntu, Debian using PPA**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kali is neither Ubuntu nor Debian.

I appreciate that Kali could be classed as a derivative, so I'll warn against you trying to continue along this path; if you try and install non-Kali packages you will likely break your Kali distribution.

This quote comes from [Kali's own documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/#non-kali-repositories):

> […] adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break.​ If any guides are telling you to do anything else than the above, this is unofficial advice, and completely not supported by Kali Linux.

My suggestion? Keep Kali as a pentest system and install a more generalised distribution as your daily driver.

---

Oh. Re-reading the four-years-old [page you referenced](https://ostechnix.com/whatsie-simple-desktop-client-whatsapp-web/) for `whatsie`, the first comment states that the application is "*No longer available*". Subsequent comments reference a Github page that is also no longer available. Consider the page (and the application) dead.